# How to pull out an email address from string of email addresses

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a column with each row containing a string of email address.  I need to pull each individual address out of the string of addresses.

Table example:

```
id  | email_id |

123 | 123@gmail.com,123_2@yahooo.com;123@facebook.com |

abc | abc@gmail.com;abc_123@gmail.com;abc@win.com |

900 | 900@gmail.com;900@tin.com;900@facebook.com |
```

---

This is an example of the expected results when selecting from the table:

```
id   | email_id

123  | 123@gmail.com

123  | 123_2@yahooo.com

123  | 123@facebook.com
```

The same result should occur for the abc and 900 row.

please help me with SQL query for the above question.

Comment: What SQL do you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two different steps.

First pull out the first email address in each line and insert it back into the table with same id:

`insert into email_address(id, email_id) select id, left(email_id, locate(';', email_id) -1) from email_address where email_id like '%;%';`

will look like this:

```
id   email_address

123 123@gmail.com;123_2@yahooo.com;123@facebook.com

900 900@gmail.com;900@tin.com;900@facebook.com

abc abc@gmail.com;abc_123@gmail.com;abc@win.com

123 123@gmail.com

900 900@gmail.com

abc abc@gmail.com
```

Then remove the email address you just popped out from the original string:

`update tester.email_address set email_id = substr(email_id, locate(';', email_id) +1) where email_id like '%;%';`

will look like this:

```
id  email_address

123 123_2@yahooo.com;123@facebook.com

900 900@tin.com;900@facebook.com

abc abc_123@gmail.com;abc@win.com

123 123@gmail.com

900 900@gmail.com

abc abc@gmail.com
```

Do the same again to push and pop the next email address out and so on...

Note: You may have to run `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` to run the update.

Then you can run something like:
`select * from email_address order by email_id asc;`  to get the values out.

Comment: Thanks a ton BK for re-arranging the question and for the answer, let me try out this option and come back on this.
can't we get the solution as expected in single attempt rather than doing it in two steps

Comment: You cannot do the update and the insert in the same query...Your problem is that you have to pop (insert) the values out of the original string and then push (update) the changes to the original string...There may be another algorithm that someone else knows...However, I had a similar issue with millions of strings of `links` to what you have and this is how I solved it...

Comment: Thanks BK for the help